# nightmare.js, on .evaluate this gives me an error on node

Tags: node.js, promise, nightmare

I'm trying to paginate by scrolling,(by clicking a button). but when i want to add some delay to that action with 'await new Promise' node gives an error on run time how to escape this from node run time this is the code snippet,

```
 let scrapedData = yield nightmare
    .goto(nextExists)
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function () {

      var links = [];
      var productList = "";
      var flag = true;

      while (flag) {
        var element = document.querySelectorAll('.load-more');
        console.log('aa ' + element[0].style.display == "");
        if (element[0].style.display == "") {
          element[0].click()
        } else {
          flag = false
        }
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); // error
        /*
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
                      ^^^
        SyntaxError: Unexpected token new
            at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
            at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
            at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
            at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
            at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
            at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
        */
      }
      console.log('all done')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `async` keyword here `.evaluate(async function {})`.

Here is a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve:

```js
const Nightmare = require('Nightmare');
const nightmare = new Nightmare({show: true});

const scrapedData = nightmare
    .goto('http://google.com')
    // You can use `await` keyword only in `async` functions
    // Async function *always* returns a promise which nightmare knows how to handle
    .evaluate(async function () {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    })
    .end()
    .then(() => console.log('All done'));
```

You can read more about `async/await` [here](https://javascript.info/async-await) for example.